# Is it safe to use StackExchange or Reddit over Tor?

Tags: ip-address

I'll bet a lot of spammers and abusers and also use Tor, and Tor exit points are limited. If I happen to be assigned a Tor endpoint that was recently used to abuse the StackExchange or Reddit, they could falsely believe I'm the one responsible. Is it safe or a good idea to use these sites over Tor?

Comment: Ther is a SSL/TLS fingerprint who avoid tahat you get someone alse ID. Ther are more identifications which separates users. Do not believe that your anonymes because your using Tor. [BrowserLeaks](https://browserleaks.org/)

Comment: You are anonymous when using Tor. Maybe the exit node will be blocked, but you can't be held responsible unless you give identifying information away or you login to an account which you use with Tor.